# How do i fix "TypeError: an integer is required"

Tags: python, panda3d

Trying to allow type a name, and when i try and type a name it crashes the game and gives me this "Type Error: an integer is required" and i have looked at other source codes for the same game and this is what they did to fix it is they added 'utf-8' to fix it.

i have tried to add utf-8 but that didn't work and that is where i'm at now. 
it used to look like this
`if not tn.hasCharacter(c):`

now it looks like this and it still breaks

```
def fontHasCharacters(name, font = font):
    if font:
        tn = TextNode('NameCheck')
        tn.setFont(font)
        for c in name:
            if not tn.hasCharacter(c.decode('utf-8')):
             notify.info('name contains bad char: %s' % TextEncoder().encodeWtext(c))
             return OTPLocalizer.NCBadCharacter % TextEncoder().encodeWtext(c)`
```

the expected result should be that i can type a name and not crash in game while instead i get "Type Error: an integer is required"

Comment: I can't run your snippet. Can you post the whole error message and trace?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to make a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. Otherwise this is impossible to debug.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n8LVnzbG thats my traceback

Comment: No, that is not your traceback, that is your error message. The traceback is everything in the output from the words *traceback most recent call last*.

Comment: yeah the error message i get is "TypeError: an integer is required" and the traceback output is in that pastebin link i made unless im misunderstanding what u are saying